# Converting dataframe column from Pandas Timestamp to datetime (or datetime.date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

*The bjillion python time formats cause more lost time than anything I do.*

Reading a file or a sql query into a dataframe gives me a column of Pandas Timestamp (i.e. type = pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp). Not the 'normal' timestamps. I want to convert to datetime.  Answers I find do not address the combination of both this particular "timestamp' and with columns in dataframes.

The below solution works, but does a more compact or 'pythonic' conversion exist?

```
df['date'] = [pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(x).date() for x in df['pdTimeStamp']]
df['datetime'] = [pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime(x) for x in df['pdTimeStamp']]
```

and the below doesn't work because of the wrong 'timestamp' type (typical of the online answers which almost uniformly address the typical 'timestamp' type)

```
df['date'] = df['pdTimeStamp'].apply(lambda d: datetime.date.fromtimestamp(d))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption without a sample df is you can use:

```
df['date'] = df['pdTimeStamp'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Thx. Isn't this conceptually similar to the list comprehension shown? However, this doesn't produce a datetime.date or datetime.datetime

Comment: yes it is a str which can be converted using pd.to_datetime(). If you share a sample df of your data that would help further.